# automate finding all images used by webpage

Tags: html, image, url, automation

When I load a page with Firebug I can see a list of all the images required by the site. 
How can I automate finding a list of the image URLs used by a webpage, including those referenced in external CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I used webkit to load each webpage and watch the resources downloaded

Comment: Where to find the images downloaded by webkit?

Answer (score 0):

With [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) it is as easy as:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$ret = $html->find('img');
```

Simple HTML DOM parser also includes options to get attributes of each object, so you should be able to grab the URL easily.  Something like:

```
$URL = $ret->src;
```

(This looks through the DOM, so I assume it will find images inserted by CSS, but I have not had a chance to test it.)

Comment: extracting img tags from HTML is easy. Even a regex will do. The hard bit is finding images referenced from external CSS or dynamically loaded with JavaScript, which that tool will not do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Firefox extensions that deal with downloading images from a web page. How about trying the "Image Download" add-on?